# libusbp failed to initialize generic interface

Tags: c++, microcontroller, libusb

I'm working on some code to read/write a microcontroller's output.
I'm fairly new to this, but from my understanding, I've installed all the necessary drivers required to read a navX2-micro's information.

I decided to use `libusbp`. It's a C++ wrapper for `libusb`, that adds some other functionality, but mainly I did not want to create my own wrapper.

I can see ASCI when I access the COM PORT on PuTTy,
but when I try to run the `libusbp::generic_interface` with a device from `libusbp::list_connected_devices` it returns either:

```
Error: Failed to initialize generic interface.  Device is attached to an incorrect driver: usbser.
Error: Failed to initialize generic interface.  Device is attached to an incorrect driver: usbccgp.
Error: Failed to initialize generic interface. Could not find interface 0.
```

I've followed the code from [libusbp's example](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/master/examples/async_in/async_in.cpp).

I've read every online post about libusbp I could find, and I've made no progress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify why you think you can use a USB serial device (CDC(ACM)) as a USB generic device? You might want to visit https://www.usb.org/ and read some of the provided documents to learn more.

Comment: @thebusybee I did some reading on [urb.org](https://www.usb.org/), I'm still kind of lost on why libusbp wouldn't work with a CDC(ACM) device. It does not mention it in the library, but that could be an experience thing. 
After some more research into it, it seems like Win32 API would be the best option to do COM PORT access with C++ if I have a CDC(ACM) device, although it would not be cross-platform anymore. Do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: Why don't you rely on the drivers of the different OSses? Specifically CDC(ACM) devices are commonly supported out-of-the-box. Then use generic file functions to open the device.

Comment: Depending on your real task (your issue sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) the library you use for your program might support already listing such devices and using them. You might want to [edit] your question to add more about your goal and the libraries you use (Qt, ...).

Comment: My real goal is accessing the data from navX2, and I'm not using any other libraries.
I'll look into using the base drivers, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use libusbp only to retrieve the name of the virtual serial port, perhaps depending on other information it can provide. This is from its project site:

> Can retrieve the vendor ID, product ID, revision, and serial number for each connected USB device.
> *[...]*
> Can retrieve the names of virtual serial ports provided by a specified USB device (e.g. "COM5").

Then use that name for standard file functions to connect to the device.